# Apache Spark: Pre requisite questions

Tags: java, python, scala, ubuntu, hadoop

I am about to install Apache Spark 2.1.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. My goal is a standalone cluster, using Hadoop, with Scala and Python (2.7 is active)

Whilst downloading I get the choice: Prebuilt for Hadoop 2.7 and later (File is spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz)

- Does this package actually include HADOOP 2.7 or does it need to be installed separately (first I assume)?
- I have Java JRE 8 installed (Needed for other tasks). As the JDK 8 also seems to be a pre requisite as well, I also did a ' sudo apt install default-jdk', which indeed shows as installed:

default-jdk/xenial,now 2:1.8-56ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]

Checking java -version however doesn't show the JDK:

java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

Is this sufficient for the installation? Why doesn't it also show the JDK?

- I want to use Scala 2.12.1. Does this version work well with the Spark2.1/Hadoop 2.7 combination or is another version more suitable?
- Is the Scala SBT package also needed?

Been going back and forth trying to get everything working, but am stuck at this point.

Hope somebody can shed some light :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install hadoop-2.7 more to whatever you are installing.

Java version is fine.

The mentioned configuration should work with scala 2.12.1.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer... Would Hadoop 2.8.0 also work? I have installed SBT, do I need to install Scala 2.12.1 as well for Spark (Want to use the binaries, not compiling). Thanks again!